# App Comments using Facebook Comment Plugin disappear after refresh

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-comments

My question is similar to this post:

[Comments using Facebook Comment Plugin disappear after refresh](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15739837/comments-using-facebook-comment-plugin-disappear-after-refresh)

I used the code generated on this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

However i am also dynamically creating different chat boxes across the site to reflect a different box for each user.

This is my code:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://bradleyhobbs.com/<?php echo $username; ?>" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10" data-order_by="reverse_time"></div>
```

Posts from regular users show up fine and stay there after refresh and page close and re-open. However comments made from the App hosting this comments plugin do not stay through refresh.

When I am using the comments plugin to post comments from my application, the comment appears and even posts to the applications wall, but when I go away from the page for a few minutes and come back, the comment disappears. If I post another comment and refresh the previous comment will appear along with the new comment but again if i leave the page for a few minutes and come back, both comments have disappeared. This only happens when posting comments from my applications account and no comments disappear when posting from a regular user or moderator account.

Here is what i have in my header:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{382253945217128}"/>
```

This makes my App the admin so posts from the app should stay like all comments from regular users do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the *{ }* musn't be present. It should be like:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="382253945217128"/>
```

try also the debuger:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

It should display the error.

regards,

Marek

Comment: Removing the brackets did not work. I commented from the App account and after leaving the page a few times I came back to the page, did a refresh, and the comment was gone (even though the comment still exists on the apps facebook wall). Running through the debugger just gives me open graph errors. Just telling me to set og:title etc...